# NO Xinput on Debian 10 Buster

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, mouse, xinput

I installed Debian 10 Buster and can't find the way to control my mouse options from Xinput like I do on Ubuntu 18 or Debian 9.

Thing is that my mouse device is a Razer Abyssus, and it comes with a very slow move configuration when you plug it to a Linux distro.

Before Debian 10, I used to have an alias to solve that. It was like this...

```
xinput set-prop 8 295 0.7 && xinput set-prop 8 298 0, 1
```

But now when I try the same it says: "xinput: command not found"

I installed Xinput but it doesn't work the same. Can't find the right options to make that alias work as before.

There is a new way to manage input devices on "Buster"?

Sorry if I'm not explaining myself very well. English not my talent. But I really hope someone can help me because the default options are so slow that it gets uncomfortable to work with this mouse.

If the change is made on the graphic applet, it doesn't change much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get

> xinput: command not found

Then you haven't installed xinput, or you haven't installed it properly. There is no other way you'd get this error if you had.

Make sure your system is up to date, and xinput is actually installed:

1. `apt update`
2. `apt full-upgrade`
3. `apt install xinput`

You will need to run these commands as root, either run `su` then these commands, or put `sudo` in front of the commands - depending on your system.

That last command should say something along the lines of `xinput is already the newest version (1.6.2-xxx).` if it was previously properly installed.

Then test if you can run the command:

```
$ xinput --version
xinput version 1.6.2
...
```

If you can't, try either or both:

- Logging out and in again
- Rebooting

If you still can't run the command after doing all of that, your system might be broken beyond repair, but I highly doubt you won't be able to. We'll troubleshoot if that happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm pretty sure that my problem resides on the "wayland" or "xorg" choice.
I think I didn't made myself clear on what I mean with the "xinput not found". I was trying to ask if the Wayland "new thing" has a new way to manage mouses and all of that, because on the Xorg server I just figured out that my alias works perfect, and all the device props are there as before. I have some images to explain better but don't know if I can share it on a comment. I'm new on asking. Thanks again! Solved for the moment.

Comment: I see, I wouldn't know, I've never tried Wayland. Didn't even know it was default on Buster, that's a bold move from Debian IMO. Either way, if you're having slow mouse problems you should check out [piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper) to configure your mouse, though it seems that isn't packaged on Debian so you will have to install it yourself.. If you want you can accept this answer, this is beneficial to both of us: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer